# Change date format in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database. In a table there's one text column that store dates in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format. I want to change all rows with the id from 2000 to 10000 into the `MM/DD/YYYY` format. What is the SQL query that can help me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're looking for something like

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET
    YourField = Mid(YourField, 4, 2) & "/" & Mid(YourField, 1, 2) & "/" & Mid(YourField, 7, 4)
WHERE id Between 2000 And 10000
```